# Communities Custom Pages Meta Tags not Working

Tags: community, seo

all I hope you are well. I have followed the guides on the developer docs and other threads from devs.

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/01/advanced-seo-lightning-communities.html
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_seo.htm&type=5

[image]

I have added the meta tags and open graph and twitter card tags to the head markup of the community. This works fine.

The problem occurs when I want to change the markup on the individual community pages under the properties section of each page. I have added the title and description and have added the meta tags, open graph tags and twitter card tags to markup by clicking the "Edit Meta Tags" button. As the documentation states this ought to work but this does nothing. Only the global meta markup gets used.

Has anyone managed to get this to work or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I opened a case with Salesforce support. If anyone is facing the same issue please see the findings of their Research and Development team posted in this [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000352967&type=1&mode=1).

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000352967&type=1&mode=1

Answer (score -1):

I'm seeing this issue as well. Global head tags are working fine.  However, page-level tags are dynamically being added and not working with the Facebook debugger tool. If anyone has managed to work around this issue, that will be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). "Me too" answers will most likely get deleted *(see [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)).* If your issue is different enough, please ask a new question and link to this question in yours. Otherwise, please contribute to SFSE in other ways (first mainly by answering) so that you gain enough reputation to add this a comment under the question.